# DRF display nested JSON

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have my DRF app. In my case, one wallet can have many entries such as income or expense. When I call my endpoint (**viewset**) I get data in this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": "d458196e-49f1-42db-8bc2-ee1dba438953",
        "owner": 1,
        "viewable": [],
        "entry": []
    }
]
```

**How can I get the content of "entry" variable?**.

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BudgetEntry(models.Model):
    STATE= [
        ('income','income'),
        ('expenses','expenses'),
    ]
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    entry_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATE, null=True)
    entry_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class WalletInstance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    viewable = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='can_view', blank=True)
    entry = models.ManyToManyField(BudgetEntry, related_name='BudgetEntry', blank=True)
```

Serializers.py:

```
class BudgetEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = BudgetEntry
        fields = '__all__'

class WalletInstanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    class Meta:
        model = WalletInstance
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views.py:

```
class WalletViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = WalletInstanceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.request.user.id

        available = WalletInstance.objects.filter(
            Q(owner=user_id) 
        )
        return available
```

Comment: *How can I get the content of "entry" variable?.* - Do you mean you want all `BudgetEntry ` data inside `"entry": []` ?

Comment: Exactly what I want

Comment: Check my answer I've assigned serializer to `entry` you can do the same for `viewable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your serializer like this:

```
class WalletInstanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    entry = BudgetEntrySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = WalletInstance
        fields = '__all__'
```